# A way to save a list of objects into a file and pull that list of objects later in Java

Tags: java, arrays, io

What I am trying to do is have a class that creates an object, then adds that object into a file.

I then will have another class that will load all of the objects from the file, into an array so I can easily reference the different objects ( and by extension, their variables).

I have tried he following code:

```java
public class EquipTwo implements Serializable  {
    
    int minDamage;
    int maxDamage;
    int mArmor;
    int armor;
    String name;
    
    public void setArmorStats(String name, int armor, int mArm){
        this.name = name;
        this.armor = armor;
        this.mArmor = mArm;
    }
    
    public void setMinMaxDamage(int min, int max){
        this.minDamage = min;
        this.maxDamage = max;
    }
    
    public int getMinDamage(){
        return this.minDamage;
    }
    
    public int getMaxDamage(){
        return this.maxDamage;
    }
    
    public int getArmorStats(){
        return this.armor;
    }
    
    public int getMArmorStats(){
        return this.mArmor;
    }
    
    public static EquipTwo makeEquip(){
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        EquipTwo EQ = new EquipTwo();
        String name;
        int armor;
        int mArmor;
        int minDamage;
        int maxDamage;
        int choice;
        
        System.out.println("What is the name of the item you are creating?\n");
        name =scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\n Is this a weapon or an armor?");
        System.out.println("1. Weapon \n2. Armor \n");
        choice = scan.nextInt();
        
        if(choice == 1){
            EQ.setArmorStats(name, 0, 0);
            System.out.println("\n What is the minimum damage for the weapon?\n");
            minDamage = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("\n What is the max damage for the weapon?\n");
            maxDamage = scan.nextInt();
            EQ.setMinMaxDamage(minDamage, maxDamage);
        }else{
            System.out.println("\n What is the armor value for the armor?\n");
            armor = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("\n What is the magic armor value for the armor?\n");
            mArmor = scan.nextInt();
            EQ.setArmorStats(name, armor, mArmor);
            EQ.setMinMaxDamage(0, 0);
        }
        
        return EQ;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
 
        try{
            EquipTwo[] equipArray = new EquipTwo[3];
            
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("EquipsFile.txt", true);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            
            oos.writeObject(equipArray);
            
                
            for(int i=0; i < equipArray.length; i++){
                if(equipArray[i] != null){
                    continue;
                }else{
                    equipArray[i] = makeEquip();
                    System.out.println(equipArray[i].name);
                }
            }
            
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The problem I am running into is that it seems whenever I run the class, it will re-write the entire file from scratch; this erases any previous data I have put into the file. I would like to save a new Object of EquipTwo each time I run makeEquip() to a file (or into an array, and then pass the array into a file) so that I can call on it at a later time from another class.

I have spent hours looking at different solutions online, this was the closest I could get. I am not looking for someone to code everything for me but rather to point out what I am doing wrong, and point me in the right direction.  Also, this is not homework; I'm just a normal human trying to learn Java from home for fun :)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are currently writing the `equipArray` to file __before__ you actually fill it with data. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

Look at where you write equipArray to your file. Each time you run your app you write an empty array to the file:

```
oos.writeObject(equipArray);
```

You need to populate your array with your EquipTwo instances before you write it to your file. Instantiate your instances, add them to your array, then write to the file.